# How to pass a Nullable<int> into a stored procedure... from F#?

Tags: linq-to-sql, f#, null, stored-procedures

I'm trying to call a stored procedure with an output parameter from F#, so I need to pass an `int?` value initialized to `null`. However, F# is resisting my attempts, saying that the object cannot be null. I've read up on the web as to why that is but my problem remains - I need to call that stored procedure. Has anyone got any ideas as to how I can do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not believe that F# has a conversion from null -> empty Nullable.  But if you instantiate a Nullable object, it will default to no value.  This is the equivalent of passing null in C#/VB.

```
myStoredProc (new System.Nullable<int>())
```

Answer (score 2):

One nice thing that F# allows you to do is to declare "generic value" so you don't have to write the lengthly construction of the value all the time.

```
let gnull = new System.Nullable<_>();;
```

Now you can just use `gnull` whenever you need to pass null as a nullable to some function:

```
> let foo (a:System.Nullable<int>) = 0;;
val foo : System.Nullable<int> -> int

> foo gnull;;
val it : int = 0
```